# Are the SDG and TDG gates hermitian?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I know that phase shift gates like $S$ and $T$ are not hermitian operators. But are the $S^\dagger$ and $T^\dagger$ gates non-hermitian too?

Answer (score 4):

A matrix $A$ is a [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) **if and only if**

$$ A = A^\dagger$$

So if $A^\dagger$ is Hermitian then that means $A^\dagger = (A^\dagger)^\dagger = A$ and so of course $A$ is hermitian.

By the way, by this definition you can see that the diagonal elements of Hermitian matrix must be real.